# Excel VBA: Why does my Range variable return nothing no matter what it is set to?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to populate a Combobox upon sheet activation with a list of company names from column C on the Overview sheet with a variable number of rows.

Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim namerange As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set wk1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Financials")
Set wk2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FinancialData")
Set Ov = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")

'Define range of company names
With Ov
lastrow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set namerange = .Range(Ov.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 3))
End With

'Add Portfolio names to combobox
With wk1.ComboBox1
.List = namerange
End With
End Sub
```

I have tried manually setting `namerange` to the actual range I want to populate the box with, but no matter what I try to set it to, it returns nothing and the `.List` throws an error.

My knowledge of VBA is very limited so I have a feeling I am missing something obvious here. I am puzzled because I have used similar code elsewhere without problems.

Comment: Are you positive that in Column C, you have data *past* row 6?

Comment: For consistency, you may want to change `Set namerange = .Range(Ov.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 3))` to `Set namerange = .Range(.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(lastrow, 3))` (remove the redundant `Ov`)

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, that’s why this has been so confusing. For reference, in this code ‘lastrow’ = 43.Setting ‘namerange’ to ‘.Range(“C6:C43”)’ also does not work for some reason.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Good point. I will get rid of that, thanks.

Comment: If the sheets exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook`, all 3 worksheet variables are redundant. Set their `(Name)` property (F4) to a meaningful identifier, then use that free, global-scope (project-scope actually) object variable whenever you need to refer to these sheets. e.g. `With OverviewSheet`, `With FinancialsSheet`, `FinancialDataSheet.ListObjects(1)`, etc.

Comment: I think you need to transpose the range.

Comment: ^ that. `.List = namerange` is an implicit member call on `Range.Value`, which gives you a 2D array - but `.List` likely wants a single-dimensional array. Try `.List = Application.Transpose(namerange.Value)`

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - thanks for the explanation, was struggling to think why.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I will also incorporate that method of referencing sheets from here on out as well.